# Why is $f(x)=x^2$ not equal to zero a.e. in regards to Lebesgue measure?

Tags: lebesgue-measure, almost-everywhere

Question as above.

In our measure theory script (and in further literature also), to illustrate the term "almost everywhere" it's stated that the function $x^2$ is not equal to zero a.e. considering Lebesgue measure while it is equal to zero considering dirac measure in 0. I have difficulties in understanding this.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you don't understand?  A good start would be to write down the definition of "equal to zero a.e." and try to prove whether it does or doesn't hold, and explain where you get stuck.

Answer (score 2):

$x^2$ is equal to $0 $ only at $x=0$ and one point has zero Lebesgue measure. However, this Dirac measure in $0$ of this one-point is $1$. This Dirac measure is defined as
$$
\delta_0(A) = \begin{cases}
0, & x\notin A \\
1, & x\in A \end{cases}
$$
for any measurable set $A$.
So, $\mu(\{x:x^2=0\}) = 0$ and $\mu(\{x:x^2\neq0\}) > 0$, where $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure, and $\delta_0(\{x:x^2=0\}) = 1$ and $\delta_0(\{x:x^2\neq0\}) = 0$. So, $x^2 \neq 0$ a.e. for Lebesgue measure, but not for Dirac measure.

Comment: Ah alright, guess that answers my question. I had difficultys in understanding the "interpretation" of the Dirac-measure. One last thing:

Where you state the definition of the Dirac-measure, couldn't you also just say x=0 since it is the specific dirac-measure in 0?

Comment: Dirac measure $\delta_x(A)$ is “indicator” of whether $A$ contains point $x$ or not.